# PHP file_exists is not recognizing a file name with a version number

Tags: php

So I apologize if this is a duplicate question but I haven't found an answer. Below I have a bit of PHP code that doesn't work like expected.

Basically i'm performing a file upload to the server, the first conditional returns true, hits the foreach loop and executes the second conditional and renames the file with the version number

the loop continues on but the second conditional never evaluates to true so the counter is never updated and the file is pushed to the server with a duplicate name.

the original file name is: file name.pdf

the second file name is: file name_2.pdf

the third file name is: file name_2.pdf

why is it not evaluating the file exists as true????

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname($file_path));
    $counter = 1;
    if (file_exists($file_path . "/" . $filename)) {
        foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
            if (file_exists($file_path . "/" . $filename)) {
                eo($filename);
                $counter += 1;
                $filename = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME)."_$counter.".strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. You've never referenced your `$fileinfo` variable. Your two `file_exists` calls are identical, so if the first is true the second also always will be.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `if (file_exists($file_path . "/" . $filename)) {...}` and use `$fileinfo` inside the second `if` .